# How do I call an Lambda authorized API Gateway endpoint from AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have to make a call to AWS api gateway endpoint which uses lambda authorizers. Can you please help me how to achieve this?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, what language are you writing in please and are you using something serverless or your own solution?

Comment: Also how are you logging in, ie what are you trying to authorize, is it a JWT or something else?

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the nature of custom authoriser used by that existing API Gateway API? Accordingly, you can pass on the necessary inputs from your lambda cod when you invoke the API.
2. Who are the existing clients that call existing API gateway API?
3. Is the API Gateway API exclusively done for the consumption from Lambda.? If yes you can enable IAM authetication for your API.

Comment: IAM Authentication is going to require the front end SDK no? Which is a bit of a pain if you're writing a multi consumer API. Not a criticism just asking!